# Eclipse diff color

Tags: eclipse, diff, subversive

I use Xubuntu with dark theme and Eclipse too. This is how look diff from `Subversive` plugin:

[image]

It's bad - I can't clearly understand the diff.

And this is my settings:

[image]

Comment: Soooo.... what is the question? Do you have problems setting the color, or are you asking for advice on what colors to use?

Comment: I see red and blue colors in options - but I not see this colors in diff :(

Comment: What theme exactly are you using? When I switch my xubuntu to "Xfce-dusk" theme (the only dark one I found in my installation) Eclipse has all sorts of visual problems (black on dark-grey text, some non-dark buttons and placeholders, etc.)

Comment: I am using Dorian theme http://killhellokitty.deviantart.com/art/Dorian-Theme-353532019